# How do I bind this type in Guice?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I have this field:

```
@Inject(optional=true)
@Named(NAMED_ERROR_HANDLER)
private PolymorphicDispatcher.ErrorHandler<IScope> errorHandler = new PolymorphicDispatcher.NullErrorHandler<IScope>();
```

and I need to override the default binding (`NullErrorHandler`). How do I do that?

Comment: `PolymorphicDispatcher` screams for Xtext. Right?

Comment: @AH: Yes, that's right but the answer should work for anyone who needs to bind a static inner class with a name and generic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have `PolymorphicDispatcher.ErrorHandler` and sons on board, but this binding should do the job:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<PolymorphicDispatcher.ErrorHandler<IScope>>(){})
    .annotatedWith(Names.named(NAMED_ERROR_HANDLER))
    .to(MyImpl.class);
```

which `MyImpl` as something like this:

```
public class MyImpl implements PolymorphicDispatcher.ErrorHandler<IScope> {
    // methods from interface
}
```

The basic principle is explained [here](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html) when you search for `TypeLiteral`. (Sorry, no HTML-ID or anchor near that section).

Comment: Thanks, that works. In my code, I used `Types.newParameterizedType(PolymorphicDispatcher.class, PolymorphicDispatcher.ErrorHandler.class, IScope.class)` but that didn't match. Any idea why?

Comment: The type from your comments matches (using some abbreviations) `PD<PD.EH, IScope>` but you need `PD.EH<IScope>`. So deleting the first argument should work also. Please also notice, that `EH` is _not_ a class let alone an inner class. It is just an interface. For that scenario `PD` is only another namespace but does not attribute to the _generic_ type of `EH`.